# SQL. Estoy buscando cómo eliminar transacciones duplicadas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estaba intentando utilizar GROUP BY, pero no encuentro muy bien la forma para utilizarlo.

```
CREATE TABLE transactions
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
userId INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES users(id)
productId INTEGER,
trxDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
description VARCHAR(30),
qty DECIMAL,
price MONEY,
total MONEY;
```

Cada userID puede tener multiples transacciones, pero en ocasiones existen transacciones duplicadas. Quiero eliminar las transacciones que se identifiquen con el mismo trxDate y userID.

Yo estaba por aquí, pero ya me perdí rotundamente.

```
SELECT [id], 
    [userId], 
    [productID],
    [trxDate],
        [qty],
        [price],
        [total], 
   FROM [SampleDB].[dbo].[transactions]
GROUP BY [id], 
    [userId], 
    [productID],
    [trxDate],
        [qty],
        [price],
        [total], 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

[image: Tabla ejemplo. En este caso, quisiera eliminar la transacción duplicada]

¿Qué recomendación me dan?

*Si incumplo con alguna normal, por favor, díganme para editar la pregunta.*

Comment: Solo has incluido la estructura de la tabla pero no tu consulta que has intentado, podrias incluirla para encontrar una solucion desde ese punto. Ademas debes definir que seria un duplicado para ti en terminos de datos (que campos comparar)

Comment: Bienvenido Binary Struggle a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya agregué más información a mi pregunta.

Comment: @F.Igor Tienes razón. Agregué más información. Muchas gracias. Sigo aprendiendo.

Comment: @BetaM ahora mismo, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de buscar/eliminar duplicados es usando GROUP BY y la combinacion de campos que formarian un duplicado:

Obtener los registros duplicados (considerando todos los campos excepto el ID), y elegir uno de los IDs (en este ejemplo el minimo ID)

```
SELECT MIN(id) as id
FROM transactions
GROUP BY userId,productId,trxDate,description,qty,price,total
HAVING COUNT(1)>1
```

Luego puedes generar una sentencia DELETE que incluya estos IDs para eliminarlos:

```
DELETE FROM transactions WHERE id IN (
 SELECT MIN(id) as id
 FROM transactions
 GROUP BY userId,productId,trxDate,description,qty,price,total
 HAVING COUNT(1)>1
)
```

Si hubiera mas de un duplicado, deberias ejecutar esta sentencia otra vez hasta quitarlos todos.

Luego de este proceso, para evitar problemas de duplicados, deberias tener una regla que chequee los datos existentes antes de ingresar una transaccion. Adicionalmente agregar un indice unico para los campos que no deberian duplicarse. Esto arrojara un error desde la BD al intentar ingresar un nuevo duplicado.

Comment: Perfecto. Muy claro y muchas gracias por la última recomendación, @F.Igor. Sólo me queda una duda, para ver si entendí bien la lectura del código, estaríamos entonces a) Identificando duplicados, en este caso los que tienen el mismo ID y luego eliminándolos ¿cierto? ¿se puede integrar la coincidencia de otra columna aquí mismo? ¿o tendría que hacer el mismo proceso, pero para esa otra variable? Si mi pregunta es inadecuada o no se entiende, hágamelo saber. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: SI te refieres a agregar mas de la condicion del id `WHERE id in (...)` podrias agregar condiciones adicionales relacionadas a otra columna `WHERE id in () AND otra_columna = '**'` pero siendo que tienen los mismos datos no habria diferencia, a menos que sea una columna que no este en el GROUP BY. SI no es eso podrias crear una nueva pregunta con un ejemplo mas completo.

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que las filas duplicadas tienen los mismos valores en todos las columnas, y que una fila puede estar duplicada varias veces.

Una solución puede ser utilizar CTE (common table expression) para enumerar las filas (particionando por todos los campos: en este caso si dos filas tienen el mismo ID pero valores distintos en otras columnas no las tomaría como duplicados) y luego eliminar aquellas filas cuyo orden es mayor a 1.

```
WITH duplicados AS (SELECT *,
                           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  [id], [userId], [productID], [trxDate], [qty], [price], [total] ORDER BY [id]) AS orden
                    FROM [SampleDB].[dbo].[transactions])
                    
DELETE FROM duplicados
WHERE orden > 1;
```